# How to change an image which is inside a div when hover on the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an image inside a div block. When I hover on the div I want my div background color to change and plus the image inside the div should also be changed. How can I get this?

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Jquery:

assuming that your html look something like this:

```
<div id='container'>
    <img src='1.jpg' />
</div>
```

add this script:

```
$(function(){
    $('#container').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).css('background', 'yellow');
        $(this).find('img').attr('src', '2.jpg');
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML Code: -

```
<div class="image-cntr">
    <img src="oldImage.jpeg" alt="" />
</div>
```

JQuery Code:- use `hover` function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery(".image-cntr").hover(function(){
        jQuery(this).find("img").attr("src", "newImage.jpeg");
    },function(){
        jQuery(this).find("img").attr("src", "oldImage.jpeg");
    },);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="change">
</div>
```

CSS

```
#change
{
width: 200px;
height: 150px;
background-color: blue;
background-image: url("first_image.jpeg");
}

#change:hover
{
background-color: green;
background-image: url("second_image.jpeg");
```

Comment: he is using image tag not css background image